# How to activate lisbox file by os.path.basename Python3 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filepath

I have a problem with playing an audio file from any directory by its filename.
I know that listbox(ACTIVE) in play function needs to take abspath to work but I can't make it to work from only basename. What I can upgrade in this code to resolve problems like this. Any help is welcome.

```
root = Tk()
root.title('mp3app')
root.iconbitmap('mp3player\\mp3.ico')
root.geometry('700x500')

pygame.mixer.init()


def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Choose file", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
    #song = os.path.abspath(song)
    #song = song.replace(".mp3", "")
    song_name = os.path.basename(song)
    song_list.insert(END, song_name)

def play():
    song_to_play = song_list.get(ACTIVE)

    pygame.mixer.music.load(song_to_play)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

Comment: how about not using the base name? if you want to you can use a dictionary, where the key is the base name and value is the full path, that way when you get the active selection you put that in the dictionary and it will give you the value which will be the full path so you can use that, also those comments above the functions are completely useless and you should provide a [mre]

Comment: "active" is not necessarily the item that is currently selected, fwiw.